# Spring STS not recognizing project structure with Gradle

Tags: spring, gradle, spring-tool-suite

I'm trying to do [this getting started guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/) from Spring. So I cloned the project using git from the command line. As I'm working with Gradle, I removed the Maven files from the repository to clean the project.

After that I open my STS and go to *File -> Open Projects from File System* and navigate to the `/initial` folder of the repository. The project is imported correctly but when I try to add some "java stuff" (packages, classes, etc.) I get several errors and I can only add folders and files, which is quite annoying for working.

To be more descriptive, I'll add some images so you can see what's happening. This is the project initially imported into STS as I described above:

[image: Initial Import]

Then I try to add some java stuff, let's say for example a source folder. So *Right Click on library -> New -> Source folder* and this is the result:

[image: Failing to add a source folder]

And in the properties of `library` I have the following:

[image]

So the question is: how can I tell to STS to recognize the library folder as a Java Project (or Gradle module, I don't know how to call it) instead of a plain folder so I can add my packages and classes?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you would like to work with Gradle, you should use the Gradle integration for Eclipse (project Buildship) and install that into your STS environment. After that, you should be able to import the projects either from disc as existing Gradle project (not as file system) or via the wizard that integrates the spring guides into STS (Import Getting Started Content). The wizard for the guides also let you choose between the Maven and the Gradle variant, so you don't need to close and delete stuff yourself.

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Correction, the wizard doesn't delete stuff. So for the GS guides which have both pom and gradle files in them, it will not delete the files you aren't using. All it does is configure the tooling to use either gradle or pom files to inform project structure. So if having the other files still there is a bother, then you'll still have to manually delete them.

Comment: I read "Correction, the wizard doesn't delete stuff." and was immediately teleported to a fantasy world with a constructive wizard.